# Extracting parameters from a Lua function callback (C api) using variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, lua, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write a class that extract the parameters passed from a Lua function call (Lua script calling a registered C function) and pass them to the registered method (IDelegate in my code snippets) so I can execute it and returns the value.

Suppose I register the following method from the GameBoard class:
`long int GameBoard::testFunct(long int);` as *"GB:testFunction"* under Lua with the following code:

```
luaL_newmetatable(mState, "GameBoard");
lua_pushstring(mState, "__index");
lua_pushvalue(mState, -2);
lua_settable(mState, -3);

lua_pushstring(mState,"testFunction");
hbt::IDelegate<I32,I32>* ideleg = new MethodDelegatePtr<GameBoard,I32,I32>( NULL, &GameBoard::testFunct); // will be deleted later
lua_pushlightuserdata (mState, (IDelegate<I32,I32>*)ideleg);
lua_pushcclosure(mState, LuaCall<I32,GameBoard,I32>::LuaCallback,1);
lua_settable(mState,-3);
```

(***IDelegate*** & **MethodDelegatePtr** are used to register methods, functions and functors so I can call them later)

then the `LuaCall<I32,GameBoard,I32>::LuaCallback` will be called *(with the Lua stack as parameter)* when I will write `GB:testFunction(17);` in the Lua-script, and then the registered method will be fired and the awaited value returned.

And it works If I register and call a method without any argument.
But if there is any parameter awaited as `long int GameBoard::testFunct(long int);` do, then I have got the following errors...

> In static member function static Tr tUnpackLuaArgs<0u>::unpack(IDelegate*, lua_State*, ArgsValue ...) [with C = GameBoard, Tr = int, Args = {long int}, **ArgsValue = {std::basic_string}**, lua_State = lua_State]’:
>
> instantiated from ‘static Tr tUnpackLuaArgs::unpack(IDelegate*, lua_State*, ArgsValue ...) [with C = GameBoard, Tr = int, Args = {long int}, ArgsValue = {}, unsigned int i = 1u, lua_State = lua_State]’
>
> instantiated from ‘static int LuaCall::LuaCallback(lua_State*) [with C = GameBoard, Args = {long int}, lua_State = lua_State]’
>
> error: no match for call to ‘(MethodDelegatePtr) (std::basic_string&)’
>
> note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string’ to ‘long int&’
>
> ---
>
> In static member function ‘static Tr tUnpackLuaArgs<0u>::unpack(IDelegate*, lua_State*, ArgsValue ...) [with C = GameBoard, Tr = int, Args = {long int}, **ArgsValue = {bool}**, lua_State = lua_State]’:
>
> instantiated from ‘static Tr tUnpackLuaArgs::unpack(IDelegate*, lua_State*, ArgsValue ...) [with C = GameBoard, Tr = int, Args = {long int}, ArgsValue = {}, unsigned int i = 1u, lua_State = lua_State]’
>
> instantiated from ‘static int LuaCall::LuaCallback(lua_State*) [with C = GameBoard, Args = {long int}, lua_State = lua_State]’
>
> error: no match for call to ‘(MethodDelegatePtr) (bool&)’
>
> note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘bool’ to ‘long int&’

I'm unable to find why ArgsValue try to pass a `std::basic_string<char>` or a `bool` when I register a method awaiting for a `long int`... It should pass a `long int`.

And here is the class I wrote to extract the parameters coming from the Lua script function call.

```
template< unsigned int i >
class tUnpackLuaArgs
{

    public:
        template< class C, class Tr, class... Args, class... ArgsValue >
        static Tr unpack( IDelegate<C,Tr,Args...>* ideleg, lua_State *L, ArgsValue... argsVal)
        {
            int t = lua_type(L, i+1);

            if( t == LUA_TNUMBER)
            {
                I32 tmpUint = lua_tonumber(L, i+1);
                return tUnpackLuaArgs< i-1 >::unpack( ideleg, L, argsVal..., tmpUint);
            }
            else if( t == LUA_TSTRING)
            {
                std::string tmpStr = lua_tostring(L, i+1);
                return tUnpackLuaArgs< i-1 >::unpack( ideleg, L, argsVal..., tmpStr);
            }
            else if( t == LUA_TBOOLEAN)
            {
                bool tmpBool = lua_toboolean(L, i+1);
                return tUnpackLuaArgs< i-1 >::unpack( ideleg, L, argsVal..., tmpBool);
            }
            //etc.
        }
};


template<>
class tUnpackLuaArgs<0>
{
public:
    template< class C, class Tr, class... Args, class... ArgsValue >
    static Tr unpack( IDelegate<C,Tr,Args...>* ideleg, lua_State *L, ArgsValue... argsVal)
    {
        //-- Execute the registered method using the LUA arguments
        //-- and returns the returned value
        return (*ideleg)( argsVal... );
    }
};
```

And here is how I use it:

```
// Specialized template returning an integer
template <class C, class... Args>
struct LuaCall<int, C, Args...>
{
    static int LuaCallback(lua_State *L)
    {    
        //-- retrieve method "IDelegate" from Lua stack etc.
        //-- then call tUnpackLuaArgs with the arguments to push the returned value onto the lua stack
        lua_pushnumber(L, tUnpackLuaArgs< sizeof...(Args) >::unpack(funcPtr,L));
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Indeed if I remove the `LUA_TSTRING` and the `LUA_TBOOLEAN` from the if/else in `unpack` function, it does compile and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, if your code contains e.g. `tUnpackLuaArgs<1>::unpack`, then the body of `unpack` will eagerly instantiate *all* possibilities (since they're all possible to reach at runtime depending on the type of the arguments on the Lua stack).

This includes e.g. `tUnpackLuaArgs<0>::apply<C, Tr, Args..., std::string>`, which means you get the error you have when `Args` is e.g. `long int` since the `std::string` can't be converted to the `long int const&` that the `operator()` of `IDelegate` expects.

You don't actually need all those possibilities: you already know what you're expecting (like `long int` in your case). Extracting an `std::string` when you want a `long int` is of no use. So instead you should try to extract from the Lua stack what you're expecting (and likely error out if the conversion doesn't work, which you won't know until runtime).

Comment: Note to mention the number of instantiations following instantiation of `tUnpackLuaArgs<N>::unpack` is on the order of N^d, where d appears to be at least 3 according to your code. You'd do well for your compilation times to avoid that.

Comment: I still do not know how to extract those parameters, but your explanation is clear and confirms the origin I was suspected for this problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Valkea You might be interested in [one solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014713/build-tuple-using-variadic-templates#comment12805453_10014713) to use tuples without recursion (it's also useful sometimes when no tuple is involved). Note that it's impossible to use recursion here.