# Variadic Tuple Order changes after Unpacking depending on Datatypes

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++14, variadic-templates

The code should call back a function by extracting arguments from a string.
However, the order changes as follows: (Visual Studio 2013 AND 2015! express)

```
"1 2 3 4"  int, double, string, int ->  3 2 4 1

"1 2 3 4"  int, double, float, int ->  4 3 2 1
```

Edit : It [works properly in gcc](http://cpp.sh/3o2a) and is a [MS Visual C++ compiler bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1075443/c-order-of-evaluation-of-expressions-in-a-braced-initializer-list-is-wrong-in-the-context-of-a-constructor-call) - Tested for VS2013 and VS2015. Does anyone knows a work around ? (Maybe using some C++14 feature? )

Edit2: I solved it adding indices to the parameters and removed the tuple too 
http://cpp.sh/9jc5

Here the sample:

```
void one(int i, double d, string s, int ii)
{
    std::cout << "function one(" << i << ", " << d << ", " << s << ", " << ii << ");\n";
}

int main()
{
    RegisterRPC<int, double, string, int>("test1", one);
    DataSource* data = new DataSource("1 2 3 4");
    functionarray["test1"](data);
}
```

And the complete code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
#include <iostream> 
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// ------------- UTILITY---------------
template<int...> struct index_tuple{};

template<int I, typename IndexTuple, typename... Types>
struct make_indexes_impl;

template<int I, int... Indexes, typename T, typename ... Types>
struct make_indexes_impl<I, index_tuple<Indexes...>, T, Types...>
{
    typedef typename make_indexes_impl<I + 1, index_tuple<Indexes..., I>, Types...>::type type;
};

template<int I, int... Indexes>
struct make_indexes_impl<I, index_tuple<Indexes...> >
{
    typedef index_tuple<Indexes...> type;
};

template<typename ... Types>
struct make_indexes : make_indexes_impl<0, index_tuple<>, Types...>
{};

// ----------UNPACK TUPLE AND APPLY TO FUNCTION ---------

using namespace std;

template<class Ret, class... Args, int... Indexes >
Ret apply_helper(Ret(*pf)(Args...), index_tuple< Indexes... >, tuple<Args...>&& tup)
{
    return pf(forward<Args>(get<Indexes>(tup))...);
}

template<class Ret, class ... Args>
Ret apply(Ret(*pf)(Args...), const tuple<Args...>&  tup)
{
    return apply_helper(pf, typename make_indexes<Args...>::type(), tuple<Args...>(tup));
}

template<class Ret, class ... Args>
Ret apply(Ret(*pf)(Args...), tuple<Args...>&&  tup)
{
    return apply_helper(pf, typename make_indexes<Args...>::type(), forward<tuple<Args...>>(tup));
}
// --- make tuple ---

template <typename T> T read(std::istream& is)
{
    T t; is >> t; cout << t << endl; return t;
}

template <typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> parse(std::istream& is)
{
    return std::make_tuple(read<Args>(is)...);
}

template <typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> parse(const std::string& str)
{
    std::istringstream ips(str);
    return parse<Args...>(ips);
};

// ---- RPC stuff

class DataSource
{
    std::string data;
public:
    DataSource(std::string s) { data = s; };
    template<class...Ts> std::tuple<Ts...> get() {  return parse<Ts...>(data);  };
};

std::map<std::string, std::function<void(DataSource*)> > functionarray;

template<typename... Args, class F>
void RegisterRPC(std::string name, F f) {
    functionarray[name] = [f](DataSource* data){apply(f, data->get<Args...>()); };
}

// --------------------- TEST ------------------

void one(int i, double d, string s, int ii)
{
    std::cout << "function one(" << i << ", " << d << ", " << s << ", " << ii << ");\n";
}

int main()
{
    RegisterRPC<int, double, string, int>("test1", one);
    DataSource* data=new DataSource("1 2 3 4");
    functionarray["test1"](data);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// --------------------- TEST ------------------
```

References used

[How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments)

[build tuple using variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014713/build-tuple-using-variadic-templates)

Comment: How do you expect to distinguish between duplicate type arguments using `data->get<Args...>()` ?

Comment: @AndreyNasonov: Well, I hope the compiler sorts that out automatically..

Comment: No, it cannot do it. What will result the call `data->get<int>()`?

Comment: @AndreyNasonov so to make it safe, the get<Indexes>(tup) helper needs to be used somehow ?

Comment: I think yes, you should use indexes instead of type names

Comment: @AndreyNasonov Do you know how this would look like ?

Comment: You can use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence instead of writing own types and `std::get` to access tuple element by index.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov OP is using the index-based `std::get`

Comment: Not everywhere (see function `RegisterRPC`)

Comment: @AndreyNasonov so? it's a member function, no conflict here

Comment: A friend of me tested in VS2015 and still got the same problem. Has the bug not been solved yet ?

Comment: The link is dead. Is there a moved link or an archived version?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
template <typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> parse(std::istream& is)
{
    return std::make_tuple(read<Args>(is)...);
}
```

into:

```
template <typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> parse(std::istream& is)
{
    return std::tuple<Args...>{ read<Args>(is)... };
}
```

Otherwise, the order in which function `read` is called is unspecified.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. The output of "one(int, double, string, int)" is still function one(3, 2, 4, 1) while the order in which read is called is correctly 1 2 3 4.

Comment: @MarcoPolo it can't be

Comment: @MarcoPolo I guess what you see is [this MSVC bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1075443/c-order-of-evaluation-of-expressions-in-a-braced-initializer-list-is-wrong-in-the-context-of-a-constructor-call)

Comment: @ildjarn is nothing if not persistent!

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki do you know  how to get a workaround for that ? Maybe using C++14 ? I confirmed VS2015 has the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

Here the fixed version using indices - in case somebody is interested.

http://cpp.sh/7mgo

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream> 
#include <strstream>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

// ------------- UTILITY---------------
template<int...> struct index_tuple{};

template<int I, typename IndexTuple, typename... Types>
struct make_indexes_impl;

template<int I, int... Indexes, typename T, typename ... Types>
struct make_indexes_impl<I, index_tuple<Indexes...>, T, Types...>
{
    typedef typename make_indexes_impl<I + 1, index_tuple<Indexes..., I>, Types...>::type type;
};

template<int I, int... Indexes>
struct make_indexes_impl<I, index_tuple<Indexes...> >
{
    typedef index_tuple<Indexes...> type;
};

template<typename ... Types>
struct make_indexes : make_indexes_impl<0, index_tuple<>, Types...>{};

using namespace std;

// --- process single datatype ---

struct anyT
{
    anyT(int   e) { cout << " int" << endl; }
    anyT(float e) { cout << " float" << endl; }
    anyT(string e) { cout << " string" << endl; }
    anyT(double e) { cout << " double" << endl; }
};
template <typename T> T read_from(int index, std::vector<string> &list)
{
    std::istringstream is(list[index]);
    T t;  is >> t; cout << "index " << index << " val " << t; anyT a(t); return t;
}

// ---- RPC stuff ----

std::map<std::string, std::function<void(string*)> > functionarray;

template<typename... Args, class F, int... Is>
void RegisterRPC_index(std::string name, F f, index_tuple< Is... >) {
    functionarray[name] = [f](string* data)
    {
        const int n = sizeof...(Args);
        cout << n << " args\n";

        std::vector<string> list;
        std::istringstream ips(*data);

        for (int i = 0; i < n;i++)
        {
            string s; 
            ips >> s;
            list.push_back(s);
        }

        f(read_from<Args>(Is, list)...);
    };
}

template<typename... Args, class F>
void RegisterRPC(std::string name, F f) 
{
    RegisterRPC_index<Args...>(name,f,typename make_indexes<Args...>::type());
}
// --------------------- TEST ------------------

void one(int i, double d, string s, int ii)
{
    std::cout << "function one(" << i << ", " << d << ", " << s << ", " << ii << ");\n";
}

int main()
{
    RegisterRPC<int, double, string, int>("test1", one);
    string* data=new string("1 2.2 hello3 4");
    functionarray["test1"](data);
    return 0;
}
```